# how to reference an "armature action" of a bow using code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to make a bow and arrow game. I downloaded a bow that has an animation(?) on it where the string is pulled back.

See: [image: https://imgur.com/a/6XeaRlr]

I want to make a script that triggers that animation (shown on bottom-right of my gif) when Player left clicks. But I don't know how to reference the animation.

Is it something like `_anim = GetComponent<Animator>();`  and then `animation.Play`? I cannot tell what the name of the animation even is to do this.

Further.. it would be awesome to be able to control the animation's length depending on how long the user has held down the button, rather than playing it in full even if user only taps left click. I'm not sure how that would be achieved?

Comment: It seems as if you need to do more reading up on animating or take a simple learning tutorial.  Regardless, yes, you would just `Play`.  As far as pulling back, you could have n Animation bool parameter that when true, plays the animation, when false it releases the arrow.  Probably need to slow down the animation and watch for input on `GetMouseButton(0)` instead of `GetMouseButtonDown(0)`.  Or not, you could set the bool parameter on `GetMouseButtonDown(0)` and reset it on `GetMouseButtonUp(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the question seems short but the solution will be long and you need to do a bit of learning. So, let's go through your question step by step.

1. I downloaded a bow that has an animation(?)

   Yes, it is a 3D bow model with an animation in it.
2. I want to make a script that triggers that animation (shown on
   bottom-right of my gif) when Player left clicks. But I don't know
   how to reference the animation.

   In order to trigger that animation, you need an [Animator Controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html) attached to the bow model instance. Then you can click that Animator Controller to open its panel. After opening the panel, you can simply drag and drop your animation there. When you first drop your animation, it will be the default animation state. However, if you don't want to trigger the animation immediately, I would suggest you to create an empty state and make a transition to the bow animation.
3. Is it something like _anim = GetComponent(); and then
   animation.Play?

   More or less like this, but you should check the documentation for better understanding, [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html) documentation explains it well and has a really good example for your use case.
4. I cannot tell what the name of the animation even is to do this.

   Once you drag and drop the animation to the panel, you will see the name of the animation to use in the script.
5. Further.. it would be awesome to be able to control the animation's
   length depending on how long the user has held down the button,
   rather than playing it in full even if user only taps left click.
   I'm not sure how that would be achieved?

   There are many ways to play with animations, for example, you can set an [animation parameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) to stay in the animation state. Furthermore, you can also disable the [Has Exit Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html) value from the transition to make it stop the animation immediately after the user stops holding the button.

Overall, when it comes to animations, Unity is quite powerful and my suggestion would be read the documentation and watch a couple of tutorials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, the empty state tip especially was helpful.